# If $G/N\cong H$ then $G=NH$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I am curious if $G/N\cong H$ then $G=NH$?

($N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.)

With this setup, we get that $NH$ is a subgroup of $G$ so $NH\subset G$. I am not sure about the other inclusion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Let $G=C_8$, $N=C_4$, $H=C_2 \subset N$. Then $NH=N \ne G$.

Comment: Nice example. Thanks.

Comment: @yoyostein, Intuitively, $G/N\cong H$ alone does not guarantee that this isomorphism is "compatible" with how $H$ sits inside $G$. There'd be chance if the [short exact sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence#Short_exact_sequence) $1 \to N \to G \to H \to 1$ split using the inclusion $H \to G$.

Comment: Splitting has nothing to do with it. At best it would show that G is a semi-direct product, but that still doesn't tell you anything about $NH$ as a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: It doesn't need to split. if the natural map $H\rightarrow G\rightarrow G/N$ is an isomorphism, then it is true that $G=HN$. Being right split for (arbitrary) groups  does imply it is a semi direct product and it follows.

Comment: @Eoin, I guess that's what I meant, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For any group $S$, let $G = S \times S$ (direct product). Then take $N = H = S \times \{e_S\}$. Then $N$ is normal, $G/N \cong S \cong H$, and $NH = N = H$ is a strict subset of $G$ unless $S$ is the trivial group (with only one element, $e_S$).

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is finite, since $|HN|=\frac{|H| \cdot |N|}{|H \cap N|}$, it is true iff $H \cap N=1$.

Comment: Interesting. Can you elaborate more on the "iff" part? I can see that by cardinality reasons it is a necessary condition, but why is it sufficient?

Comment: Using cardinality reasons, if the intersection is trivial then you get $|HN|=|G|$ which implies $G=HN$.

Comment: I think this only works if everything is finite, which was not assumed in the question.

Comment: True, but one of the counterexamples was finite. That is why I added my answer.